# How do I turn off Hibernate debug logging in JBoss Wildfly 9?

Tags: hibernate, logging, jboss, wildfly

I’m using JBoss Wildfly 9.0.0.CR2.  I have a Spring 3.2.11.RELEASe web application and I’m curious about how to turn off Hibernate logging in my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log/server.log file, in particular all the query data, like

```
[DEBUG,SQL] select organizati0_.USER_ID as USER_ID1_117_0_, organizati0_.ORGANIZATION_ID as ORGANIZA2_122_0_, organizati1_.id as id1_5_1_, organizati1_.ADDRESS_ID as ADDRESS10_5_1_, organizati1_.COUNTRY_ID as COUNTRY11_5_1_, organizati1_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_2_5_1_, organizati1_.ORGANIZATION_ID as ORGANIZA3_5_1_, organizati1_.IMPLEMENTATION_MANAGER_ID as IMPLEME12_5_1_, organizati1_.IMPORT_DATA_FROM_SIS as IMPORT_D4_5_1_, organizati1_.LTI_REFERER_DOMAIN as LTI_REFE5_5_1_, organizati1_.NAME as NAME6_5_1_, organizati1_.ORGANIZATION_TYPE_ID as ORGANIZ13_5_1_, organizati1_.PARENT_ORGANIZATI
```

In my $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml file I have

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
        <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
        </console-handler>
        <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="com.arjuna">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="sun.rmi">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb">
            <level name="WARN"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="jacorb.config">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.jasypt">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.springframework">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <logger category="org.hibernate">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
        <root-logger>
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                <handler name="FILE"/>
            </handlers>
        </root-logger>
        <formatter name="PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%e%n"/>
        </formatter>
    </subsystem>
```

Note my

```
        <logger category="org.hibernate">
            <level name="ERROR"/>
        </logger>
```

has no effect.  I have no log4j.properties or log4j.xml in my web application.  How do I turn off the Hibernate debugging?

**Edit:**

Below is how my entity manager factory is being configured in my Spring context ...

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.mainco.subco" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
    <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider"/>
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true" />
        <entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
        <entry key="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false" />
</util:map>

<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" id="dataSource" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

:

in my WEB-INF/lib directory I have a commons-logging-1.1.1.jar and I also link to JBoss' pre-packaged slf4j module (below is the snippet from the WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml file) ...

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
            <dependencies>
                    <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
                    <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
                    <module name="org.slf4j" />
                    ...
```

**Edit 2**:

Here are some other lines that precede and follow the debug SQL I'd like to eliminate from teh server log (I'd like to eliminate these lines too):

```
[DEBUG,EntityPrinter] org.mainco.subco.user.domain.User{lastName=test, creator=org.mainco.subco.user.domain.User#ADMIN1, incorrectLogins=null, address=org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Address#77F7FAC9174A4BCA9A9C5E98F50DD134, userDemographicInfo=null, roles=[org.mainco.subco.user.domain.Role#Instructional Coach], resetState=false, avatar=null, userName=coach, createdOn=2015-07-24 15:39:59.0, enabled=true, url=localhost, firstName=test, temporaryPassword=null, password=V0VW0k+ge+free1My+bS/XSm7qb0ezuvL+irH+A9l5dnMoW0YnZNda2n2Zl138N2BN51MQ==, dob=null, grade=null, organizations=[org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization#6942B22F268A4E66B50C71278E3DAA73], expiration=null, middleName=a, id=5F61E8CA3A554FE1991A05A3E960D442, salutation=null}
[DEBUG,EntityPrinter] org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Organization{country=org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Country#US, address=org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.Address#12946ACF562840458844D8083191CB73, eodbId=104112, parentOrganization=null, sampleOrg=null, createdOn=null, implementationManager=null, url=null, organizationType=org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.OrganizationType#19, userEntered=false, ltiRefererDomain=null, useExternalAuthentication=false, name=Alpine School District, id=6942B22F268A4E66B50C71278E3DAA73, state=org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.State#UT, importDataFromSis=false}
[DEBUG,EntityPrinter] org.mainco.subco.organization.domain.OrganizationType{parent=true, description=Regular District, id=19}
[DEBUG,SQL] select user0_.id as id1_117_, user0_.ADDRESS_ID as ADDRESS17_117_, user0_.AVATAR as AVATAR2_117_, user0_.CREATED_ON as CREATED_3_117_, user0_.CREATOR_ID as CREATOR18_117_, user0_.DOB as DOB4_117_, user0_.ENABLED as ENABLED5_117_, user0_.EXPIRATION as EXPIRATI6_117_, user0_.first_name as first_na7_117_, user0_.GRADE_ID as GRADE_I19_117_, user0_.INCORRECT_LOGINS as INCORREC8_117_, user0_.last_name as last_nam9_117_, user0_.middle_name as middle_10_117_, user0_.password as passwor11_117_, user0_.RESET_STATE as RESET_S12_117_, user0_.salutation as salutat13_117_, user0_.temporary_password as tempora14_117_, user0_.url as url15_117_, user0_.USER_DEMOGRAPHIC_INFO_ID as USER_DE20_117_, user0_.user_name as user_na16_117_ from sb_user user0_ where user0_.user_name=? and user0_.url=?
[DEBUG,CriteriaQueryImpl] Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from Role as generatedAlias0 where generatedAlias0.name=:param0
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the messages it's printing?

Comment: Yeah its the third line of my question -- the one with "[DEBUG,SQL] select organizati0_ ..."

Comment: Sorry, no idea how I missed that :) Looks like it's not coming from WildFly FWIW. If there's a timestamp or logger name before that portion of the message that would be useful.

Comment: Mysteriously, that is all that appears -- no logger name or timestamp before.  The only logging file I have in my WEB-INF/lib directory is commons-logging-1.1.1.jar (no log4j).  I link to JBoss' prepackaged org.slf4j (included deployment structure).  NOt sure which is the culprit.

Comment: Yes an slf4j API is added by default. Maybe try removing the commons-logging jar. Currently WildFly just uses jcl-over-slf4j for commons-logging.

Comment: You may have seen my answer to the other question, but even after removing the commons-logging.jar from teh WEB-INF/lib, the problem remains.

Comment: My only thought then is maybe Spring is doing some kind of logging configuration. If the messages only appear on the console and not in the server.log then some other mechanism is writing to stdout.

Comment: Oh shoot, I didn't mention that these are the messages appearing in my JBoss server log.

Comment: My guess is something is configuring it's own logging. You could try executing this CLI command in standalone `/subsystem=logging:write-attribute(use-deployment-logging-config=false)`. Feel free to hit me on on #wildfly IRC or [HipChat](https://www.hipchat.com/gSW9XYz69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was the console I solved this way, created the file: WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>
    <appender name="CA" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p (%F:%L) - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="info" />
        <appender-ref ref="CA" />
    </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following in your standalone.xml configuration (directly in the logger subsystem) :

```
        <use-deployment-logging-config value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the following property in persistence.xml

```
 <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
```

Comment: I'm already doing that.  I have added my Spring/Hibernate config to my question (note how it is unnecessary to use persistence.xml).

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: Spring by default uses `org.apache.commons.logging` which may be responsible for the unexpected log messages you're seeing.

Try excluding the `commons-logging` dependency from your WAR, replacing it by the `jcl-over-slf4j` module contained in WildFly.

I'm not sure if this module is exported by default - you may have to declare a [module dependency](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Class+Loading+in+WildFly) explicitly.

Comment: I reworked my application to exclude the commons-logging jar, but the Hibernate SQL messages (as well as a ton of other stuff) remain.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `spy` attribute is not set to `true` in the datasource definition inside standalone.xml

Comment: There is no "spy" attribute.  The datasource outer element looks like "<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS" pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">".

Comment: what's your mysql jdbc version, connection url and driver-class ?

Comment: 5.1.22, jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db, com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: It is very strange that your output starts with [DEBUG, SQL]. The formatting of the server.log's appender **will always** start with the PATTERN date, log level, class etc. I suspect [DEBUG, SQL] is part of previous lines written to your file. This would indicate which module is at the origin of the log trace.

Comment: You're right its strange -- that's why I posted it.  I included some lines before and after the [DEBUG, SQL] at the end of my question.  I only started encountering this problem when I moved to Wildfly 9 from JBoss 7.1.3.Final.

Comment: I would stop jboss, rename the server.log file to something like wildfly-server.log in standalone.xml config, clean up all logs and restart the application. There might be another log config on the runtime classpath that is writing concurrently to server.log.